# Any adivce about using laravel 5.2 or 5.3 for making user Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io, notifications

I woking on a project using - laravel 5.2 , 
 i will use notifcations heavly in it ,,, kind of (Facebook notifcations) , 
 and looking for using (real time notifcation ... database for now is enough )

**Hint : I'm beginner to the workflow of "Real time notifications"**

and here is A Series on this topic here :

https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io

**My question :** can i use (laravel 5.2 + socket io) to make this job done
 **or use instated of that** (laravel 5.3 and the built in notifcations logic and realtionships)

what do you think guys ... Let me know ... i'm confused about that ??

Comment: You can take a look at rethinkDB

Comment: If you use laravel 5.3 you will still need some server to actually push the notifications. or `broadcast drivers` as laravel calls them